# Powerbuilder multiple dropdown listbox selection issue

Tags: powerbuilder

Here is the scenario I'm having issues with: I have 4 dropdown list boxes (DDLB), each has the same 4 elements (horse, dog, cat, mouse).  The user can select 1 and only 1 item from each DDLB but they can also change their minds.

For example: they select DOG in the first DDLB and CAT in the second DDLB.  When they get to the third DDLB they can still select DOG but if they do, I need to deselect DOG from the first DDLB.  So basically, the selection of one element in one drop down list box causes the deselection of that element in all other drop down list boxes.

I'm not quite sure how to go about creating a solution for this scenario.  I'm using PB12.5 and non-PFC.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it programmatically. You have to place code in `ItemChanged()` event for each field and then get values for each field and validate it with current value of field.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have four ddlb controls you can create a loop to check each one of them when any of them triggers a Modified event.  You need to get the Text property for the modified control and check it against each of the others.  If it matches you can use the Clear method to 'blank out' the entry made in the other list boxes.

Answer (score 0):

We typically handle this sort of validation by

a) itemchanged code that puts up a non-blocking warning about invalid selections (we do not generally prevent focus changes in this case), and

b) pre-save verification on the window/UO that the rules have been met and stops the save if not.